# NullPointerException no retorno do método

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception

Estou fazendo um método para buscar o usuário logado no banco de dados.
Estou tendo um `NullPointerException` no retorno deste método

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/usuarioLogado", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public EntidadesAdministradores usuarioLogado(@RequestBody Usuarios usuarios) throws ServletException {

    Usuarios usuAutenticado = uService.buscarPorLogin(usuarios.getLogin());     
    usuarios = usuAutenticado;
    Long idUsuLogado = usuarios.getIdUsuario();

    EntidadesAdministradores administrador = new EntidadesAdministradores(); 
    if(usuarios.getFlagAdministrador()==1) 
        administrador = eaService.buscarUsuarioLogado(idUsuLogado);
        return  administrador;
}
```

meu método `buscaUsuarioLogado`

```
public EntidadesAdministradores buscarUsuarioLogado(Long usuarioLogado ){       
    return eaRepository.buscarIdUsuarioLogado(usuarioLogado);
}
```

meu método do repository

```
@Query(value="Select e from EntidadesAdministradores e where e.usuarios  = :parametroId")
public EntidadesAdministradores buscarIdUsuarioLogado(@Param("parametroId") Long usuarioLogado);
```

Log do Erro

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at controller.LoginController.usuarioLogado(LoginController.java:93) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
```

Comment: O log com a stack trace ajudaria a entender seu problema...

Comment: @TomMelo editei a pergunta

Comment: Provavel que um simples debug no seu método te ajude a entender o motivo do NullPointerException. Quem vê a pergunta e o stack trace, não sabe o que tem na linha 93 do LoginController.java do seu código.

Comment: a linha 93 é justamente quando o administrador recebe o método `eaService.buscarUsuarioLogado(idUsuLogado)`

Comment: Debuga o método, coloca um breakpoint nesse trecho e veja tudo que acontece. Veja se o atributo eaService está sendo instanciado.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver a questão limpando e construindo o projeto novamente. Não houve mais erros.